# whats wrong in this alternate approach to coupon collector problem

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

A particular professor is known for his arbitrary grading policies. Each paper receives a grade from the set {$A , A- , B , B- , B+, C+$}, with equal probability, independently of other papers. How many papers do you expect to hand in before you receive each possible grade at least once?

*question as i understood it*

i turn in a paper and i get a grade back and **then** i turn in another paper and i get a grade and so on. how many paper i have to write before getting all kinds of grades at least once.

*my wrong answer*

let $B_X$ represent the geometric random variable that represents the number of papers i had to write to get at least one paper graded as $X$

for grade $A \space$, $E[B_A] = 6$ (since there are six grades and all are equally likely, $ P(A)=1/6$)

so on an *average*, i should have gotten at-least one paper graded as A after writing 6 papers

since $E[B_X] = 6$  ,for all grades $X \space$ in this case.

Hence if talking about an *average case scenario*, 
after 6 papers i should have at-least one paper graded as X (for all X), because that is the definition of expected value.

Comment: Try to write down your last paragraph formally and you will find your mistake.

Comment: It is the same argument for tossing a coin.  After two tosses you have one head and one tail on average, but it takes more than two tosses on average to get one of each.

Comment: okay so that is what @Lorenzo meant by "writing again formally". i am talking about expected value of a particular grade X. But, expected value of a collection of grades is different from expected value of a particular grade.

Comment: You can take the expected value of random variables. What is your random variable for all the grades?

Comment: do you mean like E[{collection of random variables for each grade}]

Comment: That's not a (real valued) random variable